# Finding the Optimal Palette for a Set of Images

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, optimization, greedy-algorithms

## Motivation

I want to draw pictures using indexed colors. As I have limited space for colors per-palette, I want to choose palettes in an intelligent fashion, based on the pictures I want to draw. The goal is to choose a palette so that I can draw as many pictures from a set of pictures I want to draw as possible.

## Formal Description

Consider a finite, non-empty set of colors $U$ and a non-empty set of images $S \subseteq 2^U$, where $2^U$ denotes the powerset of U.

A palette is a non-empty set $P \subseteq U$. For a given $k \in \mathbb{N}^+$, a $k$-palette is a palette $P$ s.t. $|P| = k$.

For a given $k$-palette $P$, the set of paintable images is defined as $S_P = \{s \in S \mid s \subseteq P\}$, i.e. the elements $s$ of $S$ where $s$ is a subset of $P$.

One may assume that $\forall s \in S. 0 < |s| \leq k$, i.e. for every image $s$ there exists at least one $k$-palette $P$ for which $s$ is in $S_P$ and the empty image $\emptyset$ is not contained within $S$.

I am looking for algorithms to compute a $k$-palette $P$ maximizing $|S_P|$ given a set of images $S$, a set of colors $U$, and a number $k$.

For analyzing the time complexity of the algorithms, I consider the set operations $\in$, $create\_empty\_set$, $add\_element\_to\_set$, and $remove\_element\_from\_set$ to be elementary in addition to the operations commonly considered elementary.

## Observations

1. There exists a trivial algorithm for computing $P$ s.t. $|S_P|$ is maximized, by enumerating all possible $k$-palettes $P$ and computing $|S_P|$ for each and finding the $P$ which results in the maximum $|S_P|$. This algorithm performs $O\left({|U| \choose k}|S|k\right)$ elementary operations [1].
2. There exists a relatively intuitive greedy algorithm for computing $P$ with a potentially large $|S_P|$: start by sorting $S$ descending by number of elements. The first set in this order shall be named $s'$. Go through $S$ in order and try to merge every set into $s'$, while retaining $|s'| < k$. This algorithm performs $O(|S|\log|S|+|S|k)$ elementary operations [2]. However, it may compute a non-optimal solution [3].

## Open Questions

1. How "bad" can the greedy algorithm be? I.e. given an adversary that can choose $S$ for a given $k$ and $U$, how small can $|S_P|$ become?
2. Are there any "classic" problems that the problem described above is reducible to?
3. Are there algorithms that are significantly more performant (in terms of performed elementary operations) than the trivial algorithm but produce better results (in terms of optimality of the computed $k$-palette) than the greedy algorithm?

## Footnotes

[1]: For every of the $|U| \choose k$ palettes, add $k$ elements to a new palette, then for every of the $|S|$ images, check membership in $P$ of the at most $k$ colors of the image.

[2]: Sorting $S$, then merging all of the at most $k$ elements of every set in $S$ into $s'$.

[3]: Consider $U = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, $k = 3$, $S = \{\{0,1,2\},\{1,3\},\{3\}\}$. The greedy algorithm computes $P = \{0,1,2\}$ ($|S_P| = 1$), but e.g. $P' = \{0,1,3\}$ ($|S_{P'}| = 2$) would be optimal.

Comment: This sounds like an instance of the set cover problem.  I suggest you read about the greedy algorithm for set cover, which has standard bounds on its approximation ratio.

Comment: After thinking a bit about it, set cover might indeed solve a part (but seemingly not all?) of this problem:

Consider $U' = \bigcup_{s \in S} s$ to be the universe for set cover. Then the smallest cover using sets from $S$ would be a set $Q$ of palettes (not necessarily $k$-palettes!) that together allow one to paint all images in $S$.

However, this still leaves out merging palettes to become $k$-palettes s.t. $S_P$ is optimal, which doesn't seem trivial. Maybe there are even elements from $S$ not picked for the set cover which would yield a better $S_P$?

Comment: I think it's exactly an instance of set-cover.  The universe is the set of images, you have ${|U| \choose k}$ sets, one for each possible k-palette, and each set contains the set of all images covered by that palette.  No merging needed, that's already covered by considering all possible k-palettes.  Of course there is additional structure here.

Comment: Thank you, I think this answers my questions. At least (2) and (3) are directly answered, (1) may need some additional thinking, but given that it's set-cover the approximation ratios from set-covers greedy algorithm should prove useful to investigate this further. If you turn this comment into an answer I will gladly mark it as accepted! :)